# Image Upload from a different modal's view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have two models and in the update method of the first modal' viewset,(using model viewset) I'm trying to add an image to my second model but facing issues.

```
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=data)  # partial=partial)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # get image from recieved data
            # profileImage = data["profileImage"]
            profileImage = request.data.get("profileImage", None)

            ## update first modal 
            self.perform_update(serializer)
    

           ## add an image to second modal,
           secondModel.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).update(profileImage=profileImage)
```

I can see the url of image getting added but there is no image in the media directory. Actually I'm updating other field  also, thats working fine but having issue in this image field.
While direct updating in the views of the second models there is no issue. Sending formData from the frontend.

So is there a different way dealing with file objects ?

Comment: What do you mean by that  " I can see the url of image getting added but there is no image in the media directory. "

Comment: when I see the field in browseable api, the url is present against the profileImage field (it gets added). But when I click on the link it shows no image present. If i go to my media folder also there is no image addedd. but when I do it directly on the second models' view everything works.

Comment: Could you show me how you send the image as a `JSON`? as well I would like to see how the image field is represented in the admin panel.

Comment: I just changed the approach, after many failed attempts, thanks :)